# Using javascript to apply styles to certain list items

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to learn JavaScript and trying to crack  a JS Fiddle to try out. http://jsfiddle.net/Xy9Ga/ 
Objectives Using **JAVASCRIPT**:
1) Make every third list item red text and italic, starting with first item.
2)Make every tenth item bold and underlined, starting at fifth item.

I know to create the css classes and then apply them to the list items accordingly. I am having trouble trying to figure out the JavaScript side of things :( Not really looking for someone to code it for me but possibly explain the logic on how to do it. I don't know where to start

```
document.load =function() {
};
```

The two CSS classes I made are

```
    .reditem {
    color: red;
    font-style: italic;
}

.blackitem {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: underline;
}
```

Comment: If you're not familiar with a Modulus operator and if, else if conditional flows, I'd definitely start there! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators

Comment: Right now the question is a bit vague and its hard to tell what is your real problem (selecting the list items? getting every 3rd item from the list? adding a class via javascript? ...) You might want to clarify things a bit more.

Comment: You're really going to need to use jQuery selectors for this kind of thing. For example `$("ul li:first-child").css("color", "red");`

Comment: Created a fork of your fiddle and what I believe you're asking, take a peek if you get stuck! http://jsfiddle.net/realchaseadams/Xy9Ga/3/

Also, this can be done purely with javascript without a library if it's just a learning opportunity and it looks like you're more interested in control flow & operators and adding classes that have properties defined in styles.

Comment: Hello Chase, yes pretty much what I'm looking to do. I clarified the question a bit. Sorry for whoever I confused. I'm not suppose to jQuery as I could figure that out more easily. Suppose to be purely javascript.

Comment: I'm checking out the link you sent @realchaseadams thank you very much. If I wanted the second class, the black bold one, to start on fifth, would I just use two seperate for loops and start on number 4? So the first bold and underline is the fifth item?

Comment: Updated, my bad: http://jsfiddle.net/realchaseadams/Xy9Ga/8/

Comment: Also, look in to nth-child css pseudo-class: docs - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child ... samples - http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/ ... tool: http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/ --- using javascript for this may be like using a hammer to crack an egg. It'll do, buuuut...

Comment: That was exactly it, thanks for that @realchaseadams. I'm going to read over the modulus part you sent. But for the most part you answered my question. Thanks again.

Comment: Oops, took me too long to type my comment :)

Comment: Chris, nth-child css selectors are a great way to achieve the results, but this is also a great opportunity to learn javascript control flow in a way that can visually show your control flow.

Comment: Sure, fair enough, but the site's main purpose is to provide solutions to a general audience. It doesn't hurt to make sure that the best practice is on the table, even if the OP has a localized reason for not wanting to do it the easy way :)

Comment: No doubt. Good share. :)

Comment: Post your answer? You'll get cookies.

Comment: 4ever Youngz, could you mark my answer at the bottom as the solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a fork of your fiddle and what I believe you're asking, take a peek if you get stuck! jsfiddle.net/realchaseadams/Xy9Ga/8

```
var list_items = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

for(var i = 0, len = list_items.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0) {
      list_items[i].className += ' third';   
    }
    if ((i % 10 === 0 && i !== 0) || i === 4) {
      list_items[i].className += ' fifth';   
    }
}
```

It looks like you're more interested in control flow & operators and adding classes that have properties defined in styles.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `nth-child` pseudo-class instead.

I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xy9Ga/9/) to show this.

Basically, the coefficient is how often it is applied, and the part added is where it starts (that's not exactly right, but it's close enough for me).

That means for every third, starting at the first, it's `nth-child(3n+1)`, and for every tenth, starting at the fifth, it's `nth-child(10n+5)`.

[Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) is the documentation for `nth-child`.

Comment: Thank you will for the nth-child. I suppose to should of been more specific, but the object is to pretty much accomplish this using JavaScript.

Comment: So is this for an assignment? Because using js for what can be accomplished purely with css is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Willy, `nth-child` is definitely a great solution to the CSS part of the problem, but the asker was pretty clear they're trying to learn javascript, not solve the problem with what works best.

Comment: Yes yes, sorry. As I stated I'm trying to learn JavaScript. I'm confident enough in CSS/HTML/JQuery but I'm trying to learn Javascript. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is.

1. Create a Nodelist first with your all li elements in it.
2. Traverse the whole list and check whether the index is divisble by 3 or not.
3. When you got your element change the color of text by using css() function.

   ```
   var nodeList = $('li');

   nodeList.each(function (index, val) {
       if ((index + 1) % 3 === 0) {
           $(this).css('color', 'red');
       }
   });
   ```

[Here is your fiddle modified](http://jsfiddle.net/AMISingh/P29Z8/)

Comment: Has to be vanilla javascript solution. Great use of jQuery though!

Comment: jQuery is not required, and not specified by the OP. I occasionally downvote answers like this because it is technically incorrect. Please don't spam jQuery! As you can see from the accepted, the exact same technique solved the problem without adding tens of thousands of lines of code just to select some elements and do a `for...` loop :)